# jQuery validate value rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate one input. So I wanna to get this kind of rule - if field value is equal to "xxx" (text) then field is valid.

I tried this, but it seems to work only if you want two inputs to be the same.

```
$("#contact-form").validate({
    rules: {
        capcode: {
            equalTo: "xxx"
        }
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but you can always add custom validation method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("customValidation", function(value, element) {
    return value == 'xxx'
}, "Value must be 'xxx'.");​
```

And then simply use it on your field:

```
$("#contact-form").validate({
    rules: {
        capcode: {
            customValidation: true
        }
    }
});​
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7jPZx/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to create a simple "captcha"

Comment: for those that after copy/paste the code above have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`, there is a weird character after the semicolon (possibly added by jsFiddle)